# Cannot run on production devices! error while running the app on USB attached device

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling

I have attached my mobile via USB to run the app on my mobile. but while running, Android Monitor shows the error

> Cannot run on production devices!

Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.roam12.demo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Build Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.roam12.demo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: android:launchMode="standard"

Comment: You added anything that requires the device to be rooted? Also, share your `build.gradle`

Comment: Where i put this statement, when i put this in Android Manifest then it gives the error "cannot resolve standard".. :(

Comment: android:launchMode you need to use this in your activity in manifest

Comment: ok.. i try this...

Comment: Can you post your logcat ??

Comment: Thanks .. It worked

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not actually signing the release build of the APK via the signing wizard. You can either build the release APK from the command line with the command:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

or you can choose the release variant from the Build Variants view and build it from the GUI.

Or define a `debug buildtype` in your Build Gradle file.